# Python dicts in objects behaviour?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a node class with a name and a dict of its neighbors, along with the tag by which it refers to this neighbor (not necessarily the neighbor's name).

```
class node:
def __init__(self,name='',neighbors={}):
    self.name=name
    self.neighbors=neighbors

def addNeighbor(self,neighborTag,neighbor):
    if neighborTag not in self.neighbors.keys():
        self.neighbors[neighborTag] = neighbor
```

However when I perform the following:

```
foo = node(name='foo')
foo.addNeighbor('fooneighbor',node(name='bar'))
```

The dict entry {'fooneighbor',*node object*} also appears in foo.neighbors['fooneighbor'].neighbors (which I expected to be blank).

I'm guessing this is something to do with how dicts work that I'm not aware of. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions),

> **Default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is
>   executed.** This means that the expression is evaluated once, when the
>   function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used
>   for each call. This is especially important to understand when a
>   default parameter is a mutable object, such as a list or a dictionary:
>   if the function modifies the object (e.g. by appending an item to a
>   list), the default value is in effect modified. This is generally not
>   what was intended. A way around this is to use None as the default,
>   and explicitly test for it in the body of the function, e.g.:
>
> ```
> def whats_on_the_telly(penguin=None):
>     if penguin is None:
>         penguin = []
>     penguin.append("property of the zoo")
>     return penguin
> ```

So, you can fix your problem, like this

```
def __init__(self,name='',neighbors=None):
    self.name=name
    if neighbors == None:
       neighbors = dict() 
    self.neighbors=neighbors
```